# detecting autofill on chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, autocomplete

Okay, this is the story so far.

I have a login form with label overlays that hide when values are entered.
This all works fine but on chrome the autofill doesn't trigger anything.

So i rustled up the following workaround, but when i tried the remove the alert it stops working???

```
$(window).load(function(){
   alert();
   if($('input:-webkit-autofill').val()){
      $("label[for='user'], label[for='pass']").css("visibility", "hidden");   
   }        
});
```

I've tinkered with it for an hour or two now and nothing. Any ideas?

Comment: This may help in your search for an answer? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11708092/detecting-browser-autofill

Comment: Thanks for your reply Sam.  I had read through this and by it's own admittance, dosent resolve the issue.

Answer (score 3):

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        if ($('input#username:-webkit-autofill').val()) {
            console.debug($('input#username:-webkit-autofill').val());
        }
    }, 25);
});
```

This is my workaround =]
Hope this helps.