# Input Event when User Selects Datalist Suggestion?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

What events are triggered when the user selects an input option from a datalist autocomplete?

I.e. how can I run some code immediately after the user has selected a suggestion?

Comment: what datalist are you talking about? Do you mean `INPUT` element autofill list? If ya, see there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11708092/detecting-browser-autofill  There are some shitty workarounds though, using interval e.g

Comment: "after the user has selected" I'm not sure the datalist is relevant here, but rather your <input/>. See http://api.jquery.com/change/

Comment: @A.Wolff I mean HTML5 <datalist> http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_datalist.asp
@ Clint Change only triggers on blur.

Comment: @user1277170 i didn't know this one. You should have posted relevant code in question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`oninput` event is fired:

[SEE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/96R9x/)

```
$('input').on('input', function(){
    //...
});
```

Comment: Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6458840/on-input-change-event#answer-6458949