# How to validate a memorized value in an input box

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code:

```
$(":input").bind("keyup change", function(e) {
    var comboVal = $('.emailrequerido1').val()+$('.emailrequerido2').val()+$('.emailrequerido3').val()+$('.emailrequerido4').val()+$('.emailrequerido5').val();
    if(comboVal == 'nullnull' || comboVal == ""){
        $("#enviarForm").attr('disabled', true);
    }else{
        $("#enviarForm").removeAttr('disabled');
    }
});
```

What I am trying to accomplish is that when you select a **memorized value** from the input box by double clicking in the box a history of inputs shows (these values are saved by the browser (I believe)) and if you choose one of these and the field has that text you selected **the button should enable**.

Here is a JSFiddle example: [JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/kam5B/)

In the example I added a value to the first field since these dont memorize as I expalined before to show a demonstration of what I mean.

Comment: Is this relevant to your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11708092/detecting-browser-autofill ???

Comment: You could look at things like [Select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/) that give you a better control on selecting options.

Comment: Comment: Element IDs must be unique. You have many elements with the same ID. Those should be different for each element. I believe you want the classname to be `email_contactopadrino` and the ID to be like `emailrequerido1`.

Answer (score 0):

I have cleaned up the code a bit: http://jsfiddle.net/kam5B/1/

I've swapped the `class`es and `id`s so that the ids are unique, and the classes are common.

Here is a `checkEmails` function that runs the validation and enables/disables the checkbox.
checkEmails is run every time an input changes, and when the page loads the first time:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function checkEmails() {
        var nonempty = $('form .email_contactopadrino').filter(function() {
            return $(this).val() != '';
        });
        if (nonempty.length) {
            $('#enviarForm').removeAttr('disabled');
        }
        else {
            $('#enviarForm').attr('disabled', true);
        }
    };
    $('form').on('keyup change', '.email_contactopadrino', checkEmails);
    checkEmails();
});
```