# Facing a challenge in binding an event to input element when user selects text from browser cached list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In this page we have one form element with input text and submit button. By default when we load the page submit button will be disabled and then if I type something in the input element submit button will be enabled. 
Here challenge is if user enter something and click on submit, the text that he has entered is remembered by the browser and next time if user select cached text instead of typing something  how to enable the submit button with just one click.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <script
    src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#firstName').keyup(function() {
       var firstName = $(this).val();
       if (firstName.length > 1) {
            $('#submitBtn').attr('disabled', false);
        } else {
            $('#submitBtn').attr('disabled', true);
        }
    });
});
</script>
</head>
 <body>
  <form name="input" action="index.html" method="get" id='demoForm1'
     autocomplete="on" method="post">
     First name: <input type="text" id="firstName" name="FirstName"
        value=""><br> <input type="submit" id='submitBtn'
        value="Submit" disabled='true'>
  </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

Note: Please do not upgrade the Jquery  and button should be enabled on select of cached data from input element.

Comment: When you say "cached data" I think you mean browser auto-fill. Check out this other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11708092/detecting-browser-autofill

Comment: Yes I am talking about autofill, But the link that u have provided doesn't help me much.