# jQuery validate inputs realtime

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a website which users enter their contact information and discount systems process in-page to check the value of discount.

I would like to do it via jQuery/Ajax and check discount availability realtime when users fill the input has `id=mobile`, Automatically checking process starts without clicking on any "Buy" button to run the event.
I've already do it by using this code:

```
$('#mobile').bind("change keyup mouseover",function(){
loadXMLDoc(document.forms["form1"].elements["data[Onlinetran][product]"].value+"&phone="+document.forms["form1"].elements["data[Onlinetran][phone]"].value);

});
```

But this doesn't work sometimes and when input filled up with safari autofill...

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11708092/detecting-browser-autofill

Comment: Already checked didn't work as i need.

Comment: Then please provide more information as to when exactly it works and when it doesn't so we can help you more. Thanks.

Comment: Doesn't work when the autofill suggest some values and clicking on one of them then nothing happens...

Comment: As the link I posted suggested; Your best options are to either disable autocomplete for a form using autocomplete="off" in your form or poll at regular interval to see if its filled. Did you try that?

Comment: http://avernet.blogspot.in/2010/11/autocomplete-and-javascript-change.html

Comment: Disabling autocomplete is not a right practice. the customers feels bad about it. second way seems better.