# What kind of jquery/javascript event is this?

Tags: javascript, jquery

When i type something in a textfield before and now my browser has it in its "history".

Like if I typed in "idp" and when I go back to the same page and I then type just "i", it comes up with something like a dropdown selection and "idp" would be listed there.

If I selected "idp" from the selection, what javascript/jquery is triggered? I want to write additional codes to handle such an event

Here's a screenshot of what I'm talking about: http://i.imgur.com/tYgkgI9.png

Thanks a lot

Comment: its an Autofill settings of a browser you can turn on/off through your code

Comment: This is browser autofill

Comment: What's with the downvotes? Perfectly reasonable to ask what event, if any, is triggered when the browser auto-fills.

Comment: Please see my question from a while back -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11708092/detecting-browser-autofill

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chrome fires the `input` event when you choose something from the auto-fill list, which seems reasonable. In general, I'd expect a browser to fire `input`, `change`, or both when doing that. (`change` will typically only be fired when focus leaves the control, though.) [Here's a test page](http://jsbin.com/qixuni/1/) that looks for `input`, `change`, and `click`.