# does autofill feature detection exist?

Tags: javascript, modernizr, autofill

I want to run some JavaScript only if the browser doesn't natively support autofill. (I'm not looking to detect autofill events, or turn autofill off, but just see if the browser supports the feature.) Modernizr seems to come up short, but maybe I'm just not looking hard enough - does anybody know if I can detect if a browser has autofill support?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detecting Browser Autofill](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11708092/detecting-browser-autofill)

Comment: I know it's not a very satisfying answer, but unfortunately it is the answer.  There's no simple way as far as I know to detect it.  Your best bet is to always use your code.  Most modern browsers support autofill these days anyways, it is typically only disabled by the user

Comment: @Pheonixblade9 the question you're linking to is about detecting the autofill event, but I'm looking to detect the feature. Autofill support is pretty widely supported on desktop, but as far as I know, completely unsupported on mobile.

Comment: really?  My Android phone has autofill.. but I use Chrome on my phone.

Comment: ah, you're right - i'll amend that to "completely unsupported on iOS Safari." :)

Comment: Perhaps you should filter based on user agent then?

Comment: @Pheonixblade9 certainly doable, but this has all the problems inherent in user agent detection vs feature detection, so I was hoping that feature detection for this existed. If not, then I'll reevaluate. Thanks!

Comment: It's also possible that modernizr would work for you - on my phone so I can't look it up, but take a look!

Comment: @carpeliam - autofill can mean a number of different things - do you mean auto_complete_?