# jQuery - Listen to User click on the Auto Suggest Option provided by browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser

This is my input box.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="contestCode" name="contestCode" required >
```

My jQuery Snippet which checks for `keyup` event and `paste` event

```
$('#contestCode').on({
            keyup : function(){
                checkContestCodeIfExists($(this));
            },
            paste : function(){
                checkContestCodeIfExists($(this));
            }
    });
```

But when the user clicks on the autoSuggest provided by the browser **(Code exists for the auto suggest provided by the browser because I already gave that code as input once)** ,I am not able to listen to that event. How can I do that in jQuery?

Comment: You could potentially hook into the change event of the text input. Though that would not fire until the element loses focus.

Comment: Also - you might check this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11708092/detecting-browser-autofill

This also might be a good place to look:
https://github.com/tbosch/autofill-event

Comment: thanx for your suggestion @jeremysawesome. solved it using the change method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it using the `change` event as per the suggestion in comments

```
$('#contestCode').on({
            keyup : function(){
                checkContestCodeIfExists($(this));
            },
            paste : function(){
                checkContestCodeIfExists($(this));
            },
            change : function(){
                checkContestCodeIfExists($(this));
            }
    });
```

Comment: Nice try dude , crossed me :)