# Javascript For Surveys: Calculating Age from Birth date on Page Load From Prefilled Info

Tags: javascript, jquery

I currently have the following Javascript action on one of my SurveyGizmo surveys.

The purpose of it is to calculate the exact age (by a specific date) of when someone specifies their birth date.

**However**, we often prefill info into our surveys. The problem is that the script doesn't trigger when their is a date already prefilled into the dob textbox.   Is there a way to ensure the age textbox updates whenever the page is loaded as well as when the textbox is changed?

Thank you for any help you may provide/

```
$SG(document).ready(function(){
    if ($SG('body').attr('id') != 'app') {
        var textbox = $SG('#sgE-2604126-33-6-element');  //dob box
        $tgtbox = $SG("#sgE-2604126-33-254-element"); //age box
        $minage = 21;  //minimum age
        $errortxt = 'You must be at least ' + $minage + ' years old to continue';

        textbox.change(function(){
            console.log($SG(this).val());
            var birth = $SG(this).val();

            function getAge(birth) {

                var d = new Date(2016,3,16);
                var n = d.getTime();
                console.log(n);

                var c = Date.parse(birth);
                console.log(c);

                var a = (d - c) /(1000*60*60*24*365);
                var result=(a*100)/100;
                console.log(result);

                $tgtbox.val(result);
                //alert(result);
            }
            getAge(birth);
        });
    }

    //submit validation  
    $('.sg-survey-form').submit(function(e){

        if($tgtbox.val() < $minage) {
            //alert($tgtbox.val());
            //alert($minage);

            $('.sg-error-message').text($errortxt).fadeIn('slow');
            e.preventDefault();

        }

    });  //end submit validation


});
```

Comment: Can you please explain how you "prefill info" into the surveys? It's important to know how and when this "prefill" is done, so we can recommend a method to update the display at the right time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you'll have to do it by [running the check function regularly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11708092/detecting-browser-autofill).

Here's some code snippet for that:

```
$.fn.allchange = function (callback) {
    var me = this;
    var last = "";
    var infunc = function () {
        var text = $(me).val();
        if (text != last) {
            last = text;
            callback();
        }
        setTimeout(infunc, 100);
    }
    setTimeout(infunc, 100);
};


$("#myInput").allchange(function () {
    alert("change!");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code isn't setting the age display until a change event occurs in the text box. If there's something pre-loaded in the text box, you need to initialize the age display.

To initialize the age display, looks like you just need to call the code you're firing upon `textbox.change` once at load time. Like this:

```
function setAge() {
    console.log($SG(this).val());
    var birth = $SG(this).val();

    function getAge(birth) {

        var d = new Date(2016,3,16);
        var n = d.getTime();
        console.log(n);

        var c = Date.parse(birth);
        console.log(c);

        var a = (d - c) /(1000*60*60*24*365);
        var result=(a*100)/100;
        console.log(result);

        $tgtbox.val(result);
        //alert(result);
    }
    getAge(birth);
}

// run upon textbox change event
textbox.change(function() { setAge(); } );

// run right now
setAge();
```

Or here's the code snippet without the unnecessary bits:

```
function setAge() {
    console.log($SG(this).val());
    var birth = $SG(this).val();
    var d = new Date(2016,3,16);
    var n = d.getTime();
    var c = Date.parse(birth);
    var a = (d - c) /(1000*60*60*24*365);
    var result=(a*100)/100;
    $tgtbox.val(result);
}

// update age upon textbox change event
textbox.change(function() { setAge() } );
// update age right away
setAge();
```