# animationend event not firing

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I am trying to add an `animationend` event to an element, but the event doesn't get fired. What am I doing wrong, and how can I fix it?

#### JSFiddle

```js
var btn = document.getElementById('btn');
var elem = document.getElementById('elem');
var timeOutFunc;

btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  elem.classList.add('show');
  clearTimeout(timeOutFunc);
  timeOutFunc = setTimeout(function() {
    elem.classList.remove('show')
  }, 1000);
});


elem.addEventListener('animationend', function(e) {
  console.log('animation ended');
});
```

```css
#elem {
  background-color: orange;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 500ms ease;
}
#elem.show {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: none;
}
```

```html
<button id="btn">Press Me</button>
<div id="elem"></div>
```

Comment: where is  the animation ? I don't find any animation css script in your code?

Comment: @prasad There's no animation, but there's a `transition`. When the opacity changes, css will animate it. Whenever `show` gets removed, it transitions.

Comment: Is not animation event its just changing the class. transistion != animation see my answer

Comment: in any case that u fixed ur code ...    addEventListener will not run on          IE 6.7.8

Comment: @AlirezaMasali I'm not targeting those.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

There are two separate animating events.

1. animationend
2. transitionend

When using the css `transition` use `transitionend`, and when using `@keyframes/animation`, use `animationend`.

Answer (score -2):

You need to modify the animation style property of the element this is your updated example at [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/elshenawy000/ke5nksoy/1/)

```
    #elem {
       background-color: orange;
       width: 100px;
       height: 100px;
       opacity: 0;
       transition: opacity 500ms ease;
       }
      /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
     @-webkit-keyframes myopacity {
          0%   { opacity: 0; }
         100% { opacity: 1; }
      }

     @keyframes myopacity {
       0%   { opacity: 0; }
       100% { opacity: 1; }
     }
     #elem.show {
       WebkitAnimation : myopacity 1s 1; 
      animation : myopacity 1s 1;     
     }

    var btn = document.getElementById('btn');
    var elem = document.getElementById('elem');
    var timeOutFunc;

    btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
        elem.classList.add('show');
      /*  clearTimeout(timeOutFunc);
        timeOutFunc = setTimeout(function() {
            elem.classList.remove('show')
        }, 1000);*/
    });


    elem.addEventListener('animationend', function(e) {
        console.log('');
        alert('animation ended');
        elem.classList.remove('show')
    });

  <button id="btn">Press Me</button>
   <div id="elem"></div>
```