# Detect what form autocomplete value was selected

Tags: javascript, html, browser

In HTML we can say to a form to show browser autocomplete. But is it possible to detect if some of the autocomplete values was selected?
[image]

Comment: there are already some questions. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11708092/detecting-browser-autofill

Answer (score 0):

The browser fires an autocompletechange event. You can do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('EnterElementHere').on('autocompletechange change', function () {
      $('EnterElementHere').html('You selected: ' + this.value);
    }).change();
});
```

Read [here](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-change)

Comment: i don't use jquery and jquery autocomplete