# How can I fetch the value of a field Chrome has autofilled?

Tags: javascript, angular, google-chrome, autofill

I have a form with a username and password field and a login button. The login button is only enabled when the username field is not empty.

However when Chrome autofills the fields the login button stays disabled until I click somewhere on the page.

How can I make my app recognise that the username is not blank.

I created this javascript, which executes after the fields have been populated:

```
$timeout(function(){
            var field= angular.element('#username');
            if (field.length && field.val().length > 0) {
                var button= angular.element('#login_button');
                button.removeClass('disabled');
            }
        }, 1000);
```

But it doesn't work because `field.val()` is always just read as an empty string.

Comment: I think this is a known Chrome bug, I've run into a number of sites where they thought the password wasn't entered when Chrome auto-filled it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detecting Browser Autofill](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11708092/detecting-browser-autofill)

Comment: @GuillaumeSerrat That question is from 2012. Surely things are different now.

Comment: @Urbycoz one of the solutions seems to still be relevant: The :-webkit-autofill CSS pseudo-class matches when an element has its value autofilled by the browser