# Detect autofilled input in Firefox

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, firefox, autofill

I need your help.

I made some material design like inputs form my design but I have problem with autofilled state.

Floating labels are not moved to top when inputs are autofilled (they are when clicked in input).

I resolved this for Chrome because Chrome has `:-webkit-autofill` pseudo class but what about Firefox?

Is there any hack for this?  Some JS trick?

Thanks.

Comment: Here u have my working workaround:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11708092/detecting-browser-autofill/65174904#65174904

Answer (score 2):

Answer for this was very easy, you just need to check value of input `$(this).val();` It works in FF.

Comment: The browser actually prevents exposing the value of the inputs from autofill as a security measure... so there is actually no value, or it is `undefined`

Answer (score 1):

Are you try use `autocomplete="off"` for your input ?

And I think  `:-moz-autofill` may be instead of `:-webkit-autofill`.

Comment: I tried, unfortunetly autocomplete="off" is ignored by browser and :-moz-autofill not working currently

Answer (score 0):

I just played with same issue today and found out that:
if css rules for filled input are assigned to `:-webkit-autofill` and followed by other selectors, Firefox just ignore whole set of rules.
Therefore i needed to add it as separated css rules even they are totally identical:

```
.bmd-input :focus ~ label,
.bmd-input .filled ~ label{
    color: rgba(66,66,66,1);
    font-size: 12px;
    top: 0;
    line-height: 24px;
    cursor: default!important;
}
.bmd-input input:-webkit-autofill ~ label,
.bmd-input textarea:-webkit-autofill ~ label{
    color: rgba(66,66,66,1);
    font-size: 12px;
    top: 0;
    line-height: 24px;
    cursor: default!important;
}
.bmd-input input:-moz-autofill ~ label,
.bmd-input textarea:-moz-autofill ~ label{
    color: rgba(66,66,66,1);
    font-size: 12px;
    top: 0;
    line-height: 24px;
    cursor: default!important;
}
```