# Autocomplete in browser not working with knockout.js

Tags: google-chrome, knockout.js, autofill

I have the following form element:

`<input type="text" id="fullName" data-bind="textInput: fullName" maxlength="50" autocomplete="name">
<label for="fullName">Name</label>`

However, the knockout binding prevents from taking advantage of the autocomplete feature of browsers. Is there a way to catch the `autofill` browser event? Or is there a workaround to bind data from autofill to the KO variable?

PS : I'm looking for a solution that is cross-browser compatible. I have tried the solution provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41530164/10540057), but it doesn't serve my purpose :

Answer (score 0):

This is the old time issue (sort of security related), not fixed yet anywhere. I would suggest to use some shim like https://github.com/iamJoeTaylor/vanilla-autofill-event to get around this.