# How to automatically submit form when browser autofills the input values

Tags: html

I have this form:

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="tel" name=phone_no required>
    <input type="password" name=password required>
    <button type="submit">Sign In</button>
</form>
```

How can I automatically submit this form when browser auto-fills these input fields in form ?

Comment: Why would you want to do that ?

Comment: so that use doesn't have to click on submit/SignIn button.

Comment: what if autocomplete was not what user wanted to fill ? or it was old data

Comment: hmm, i guess i have to add extra code to handle that.

Comment: I think it smells like trying to get data without user permission. Just saying

Comment: oh, interesting perspective. I wanted to make user experience bit seamless. You know. It's just that It seems redundant for user to click "Submit" button when those fields are filled in automatically by browser.

Comment: I understandddd

Answer (score -1):

You can do this using Javascript :

(1) Get html elements with selector :

> document.getElementsByName(..)

(2) Check if the elements contains any value.

> element.value

(3) In that case, trigger an event which click on the submit button :

> button.click();

Comment: that's ok, but how do I fire/trigger this on autofill by browser?

Comment: using event listener "on change" on inputs ?

Comment: but that would fire every time user makes some change. i.e. let's say he/she is typing "ark4579" it would fire every time there is change i.e. when value is "a", "ar", "ark"... and so on. No?

Comment: The problem to use "on change" is that event will be triggered on every updates.

Are you using jQuery ?

Comment: Okay, before you can try to use in this function :

window.onload = function () { 

...

}

Comment: I think that every browser could do it differently so it will be very hard to detect in my opinion. Here is the answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11708092/detecting-browser-autofill  Post by DrNio with 11 votes could be it.

Comment: yeah, i went through this question and ignore answer because it's too old and we have come a long way since 2012. but this might be it.