# detect autofill to input of type text by bootstrap datepicker

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, input, datepicker, autofill

I have a bootstrap DatePicker, and next to it is an empty Input of type Text.

Whenever a date is selected in the DatePicker, this value is autofilled (not autocomplete) into the Input.

I want to detect this by attaching an event to the Input. There doesn't seem to be a solution after trying almost a hundred different solutions.

From this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11708092/detecting-browser-autofill) it says there is no way to attach an event due to browsers all handle autofill differently.

The solution from the page says is to use polling.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="product-options">
        <div class="input-group date" data-picker-class="product-options pp-date-time-picker">
        <input type="text" name="option[248]" value="2020-11-19" data-date-format="YYYY-MM-DD" id="input-option248" class="form-control">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="button"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></button>
        </span></div>
</div>

$('.product-options input[type="text"]').on('blur input change keyup select propertychange', autoUpdatePriceUsingDate);

<div class="bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget dropdown-menu top pull-right product-options pp-date-time-picker" style="display: none; position: absolute; inset: auto 20px 127.4px auto;">...</div>
```

The bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget class hooks to this function via click, keydown and mousedown:

```
function() {
  return a.apply(b || this, e.concat(d.call(arguments)))
}
```

Is there a 2020 solution?

Comment: Can you provide some code?

Comment: added the relevant code. thx.