# Ajax event for password fill in by browser in Primefaces

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces

I have written a password validator in Primefaces which will trigger validation whenever typing.

```
<p:password id="password1" class="col-11" value="#{bean.password1}" label="Password">
    <p:ajax update="@(form :input:not(button))"/>
    <p:ajax event="keyup" process="@this" update="password1Icon "
        global="false" listener="#{controller['checkPassword'](bean)}"/>
    <p:ajax event="change" process="@this" update="password1Icon "
        global="false" listener="#{controller['checkPassword'](bean)}"/>
</p:password>
```

But the validation cannot be triggered by browser password fill in. Which ajax event can listen the browser password fill in?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cRnlb.png)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11708092/detecting-browser-autofill

Comment: Thx a lot, Jasper :)