# Javascript function doesn't work when chrome auto-fill forms

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, autofill

I have a login form where, if the fields are filled with data, a javascript (jquery) adds a class to them.

The problem appears when the fields are auto-filled by Google Chrome if you save the access credentials. Is there a way to check if Chrome (or any other browser) has autofill the field and launch the JS function so the correct classes are applied?

EDIT giving any input from the keyboard/mouse, the script is fired and it works correctly. Unfortunately, I want it working without user input but o page load.

Example below

### main.html

```
<input type="password" class="input100" name="password">
```

### main.js

```
$('.input100').each(function(){
        $(this).on('blur', function(){
            if($(this).val().trim() != "") {
                $(this).addClass('has-val');
            }
            else {
                $(this).removeClass('has-val');
            }
        })    
    })
```

Comment: Try on change. Blur happens when the user tabs out, auto fill doesn't do that.

Comment: @cloned same result. I have also noticed that, when the form is auto-filled after the page has been load, as soon as I click any key on the keyboard or the right/left mouse button, no matter where, the script is fired and works correctly. Unfortunately I need it to work once the page is loaded and without input from the user if the form is autofill

Comment: Use $(document).ready and then use the same loop without the on blur function.

Comment: @Grumpy still doesn't work. I think a solution could be to make automatically click a keyboard button (such as arrow up) when the page is fully load (as if I do it manually the script fires correctly)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Detecting Browser Autofill](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11708092/detecting-browser-autofill)

Comment: @cloned nope, unfortunately, I checked that question previously too