# Chrome cash values in inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome

I have a registration page. There I have a form with 2 required inputs - email and password.

```
<div class="row row_registration">
    <label for="email">Электронная почта</label>

    <div class="row-w">
        <input id="email" name="email" class="text v" required="required" type="email" value="">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row row_registration">
    <label for="password">Пароль</label>

    <div class="row-w">
        <input id="password" name="password" class="text eq" minlength="7" required="required" type="password" value="" maxlength="14">
    </div>
</div>
```

Also I have a submit button (surprise!), which has an attribute "disabled".

```
var checkRequiredInput = function(){
    if($("#email").val().length > 0 && $("#password").val().length > 0) {
        $(".registration__button button:submit").attr("disabled", false);
    }
};
```

I bind keyup on inputs. And! I run this function when document is ready.

```
checkRequiredInput();
$("#email, #password").on("keyup", function(){
    checkRequiredInput();
});
```

But I have some values on this page that google chrome puts in my inputs and it happenes.. **when?**
Because my function changes nothing when I run it when document is ready. I understand, that on this moment inputs are empty. I can't use setTimeOut because of different internet connection.
**Does any event or something exist to bind the moment when chrome does this.**

Comment: Can you provide more for this? Calling of your function?

Comment: But what is the question? still searching for it.......

Comment: You surely want to bind `input` event to both input elements and set `autocomplete="off"`

Comment: My question is: does any event or something exist to bind the moment when chrome does this. onload and document.ready are not appropriate.

Comment: I know that I just can to use autocomplete="off". But if here is another way to win this, whould be much better

Comment: ok your question is browser save username/password that you want to check for `disable` your `submit` button if `no string` present and if somthing is their you want to make it `enable`. Verify me if i am wrong.

Comment: Not really... I just want to run my function after the moment when chrome does his stuff

Comment: i found only a way is `autocomplete="off"` we can not trace that event.

Comment: you can try somthing from this if any event binding works for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3314240/detecting-autocomplete-on-form-input-with-jquery

Comment: Okay thank you anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. As practice shows - autocomplete and cash values for inputs are no the same.
    So even if I add attribute `automplete` my problem stays.
2. It is possible to combine 2 events and bind `keyup` and `change`. It works but shows design changes (disabled button) only after next any action: click, focus, blur, keypress and etc. Much better, but still not good enough.
3. How browser desides where to put values? By `type` and user's previous actions on this site. I can't change types of inputs.
4. Also I know that `https` does not allow browser to use autocomplete. Only hardcore.

How did I resolve my problem: html5 helps alot (I added many different restictions to inputs) so designer and I desided to delete `disabled`. The rest will be happened automatically. Thank you, HTML5!