# jQuery on input for autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

I have a jQuery function that returns whenever an `input` event gets fired on an `input` field:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on("input", ".input input", function(event) {
        //Interesting stuff
    });
});
```

However I have noticed that it does not work whenever the browser autocompletes/autofills something.

Now I am well aware that there are quite some topics about it already, but they all seem to be a bit dated as web development is going fast.

Note: I do **not** want to disable autocomplete.

So is it currently possible to detect an `autocomplete`/`autofill` event from a browser?

What other options do I have if this is not possible?

Comment: Does it still not work when you use `autocomplete="off"` within your form field?

Comment: @pattmorter That disables autocomplete, which I do **not** want.

Comment: Strugled with this myself last week, tried `onkeyup` and `onclick` - both not working. (After that I gave up because it wasn't that important in my case.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Any event triggered on autocomplete?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8548533/any-event-triggered-on-autocomplete)

Comment: @adeneo Though that question is dated by 2 years, hence the sort of repost. Maybe I should go with checking after 100ms up to 1000ms since the document has loaded and manually fire the `.input()`'s of all the elements in all forms.

Comment: autocomplete fires on certain element names, so if you have an input with say the name "firstname", you could use an interval to check any changes in the value on that element that didn't trigger an actual change event, and clear the interval if the user does add something to an input. I think that's the only way, as there are no events triggered from the browsers autocomplete.