# How to call a function when default browser autocomplete list item selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser, autocomplete

Is there is any event by which we can execute some code when user select a suggested list item from browser.I am talking when user select one of email id for login.Which is suggested by browser.

- i have tried `change` ,`mouseover`,`mouseout`,`change`,`keyup`,`keydown` etc.
- its working fine when user select it by key because we have key evennts,but when user select emailid from mouse click its not working.
- Its there is any reliable trick please say, but it should not related to position as its different for different place.

if its not possible with default suggestion,please suggest any thing else.But only if its not possible.

Comment: Try this its working ,I tried alot and found this working ....`$('html').bind('input',function() {}`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33412873/3143384 this is full answer.