# How to redirect while select value from autocomplete textbox without click on submit?

Tags: php, autocomplete

code:

```
<script>
    function autocomplete(inp, arr) {
      inp.addEventListener("input", function(e) {
          var a, b, i, val = this.value;
          closeAllLists();
          if (!val) { return false;}
          currentFocus = -1;
          a = document.createElement("DIV");
          a.setAttribute("id", this.id + "autocomplete-list");
          a.setAttribute("class", "autocomplete-items");
          this.parentNode.appendChild(a);
          for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if (arr[i].substr(0, val.length).toUpperCase() == val.toUpperCase()) {
              b = document.createElement("DIV");
              b.innerHTML = "<strong>" + arr[i].substr(0, val.length) + "</strong>";
              b.innerHTML += arr[i].substr(val.length);
              b.innerHTML += "<input type='hidden' value='" + arr[i] + "'>";
              b.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
                  inp.value = this.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;
                  closeAllLists();
              });
              a.appendChild(b);
            }
          }
      });
      inp.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
          var x = document.getElementById(this.id + "autocomplete-list");
          if (x) x = x.getElementsByTagName("div");
          if (e.keyCode == 40) {
            addActive(x);
          } else if (e.keyCode == 38) {
            addActive(x);
          } else if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            e.preventDefault();
            if (currentFocus > -1) {
              if (x) x[currentFocus].click();
            }
          }
      });
      function addActive(x) {
        if (!x) return false;
        removeActive(x);
        if (currentFocus >= x.length) currentFocus = 0;
        if (currentFocus < 0) currentFocus = (x.length - 1);
        x[currentFocus].classList.add("autocomplete-active");
      }
      function removeActive(x) {
        for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
          x[i].classList.remove("autocomplete-active");
        }
      }
      function closeAllLists(elmnt) {
        var x = document.getElementsByClassName("autocomplete-items");
        for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
          if (elmnt != x[i] && elmnt != inp) {
            x[i].parentNode.removeChild(x[i]);
          }
        }
      }
      document.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
          closeAllLists(e.target);
          });
    }
    var countries = ["Afghanistan","Albania","Algeria","Andorra","Angola","Anguilla","Antigua & Barbuda","Argentina","Armenia","Aruba","Australia","Austria","Azerbaijan","Bahamas","Bahrain","Bangladesh","Barbados","Belarus","Belgium","Belize","Benin","Bermuda"];
    autocomplete(document.getElementById("myInput"), countries);
</script>

<form autocomplete="off">
    <div class="autocomplete" style="width:300px;">
        <input id="myInput" type="text" name="myCountry" placeholder="Country">
    </div>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

In this code I have an autocomplete text box which is work perfectly. Now, when I click on submit button and redirect through action its working but I want when I type any letter then select data through arrow key or mouse then it will redirect to another page. So, How can I do this ?Please help me.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

I see two parts to this question, first being you would want to attach an event handler to the textbox for selecting from the autocomplete dropdown. I would check out this page for help on that: [Any event triggered on autocomplete?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8548533/any-event-triggered-on-autocomplete)

The second part of the question would be how to submit the form programmatically, which just involves getting the form and then calling the submit() method on it [How to submit a form using javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9855656/how-to-submit-a-form-using-javascript)