# AspxClientTextBox: how to detect on client side that AspxTextBox field has been changed

Tags: devexpress

I am using DevExpress v 10. On a web pafe I have an AspxTextBox field.
I need the followig functionality on client side: to perform some my JavaScript code IMMEDIATELY after content of the field has been changed.

The problem is: how to recognize this situation? The events TextChanged and ValueChanged are not suitable for me: they are fired only after the field loses its focus.
The event KeyUp is almost OK, but it is not fired when the field is modified using context menu: say, right click mouse and select Cut or Paste or Delete in the context menu.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are right.

A browser does not raise the “change” event when modifying the input’s value in this manner.

Refer to my answer at: [How to call a JS function, on data selection in  from AUTOCOMPLETE list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8834030/how-to-call-a-js-function-on-data-selection-in-input-type-text-from-autocom/8865109#8865109)

Hope this helps.

Otherwise, it is possible to subscribe to the required actions (cut, copy, past) via the jQuery library.

Refer to the [How to attach the copy / cut / past event via the jQuery](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q304646.aspx) DX resource to see this approach in action.

Comment: Yes, I have tried this solution. But:
- the handler for the ASPxTextBox is not called at all;
- the handler for the INPUT is called, but not always. It is not called if I change the field using Context Menu (say, its Cut or Delete commands)

I have been using MSIE 9.