# ASPxTextBox wih NullText loses value when browser window loses focus

Tags: asp.net, devexpress

I have an ASPxTextBox with a NullText. It is used for a user name. Some users are copying their user name from the registration email into this text box. When they do it via right click and the context menu and go back to their email client to copy the password, the text box gets emptied, i. e. NullText is displayed.
I can reproduce this. However, when using Ctrl+V to paste the user name, it is persistent.
It seems to me that the ASPxTextBox is looking for a keydown event or something similar to decide if the text has changed.
How can I make the text persistent in all cases?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this behavior is a side effect of the browser/form AutoComplete feature.

Can you try to reproduce this issue with a regular  with the placeholder attribute (HTML5)?

If the behavior is the same, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8834030/how-to-call-a-js-function-on-data-selection-in-input-type-text-from-autocom/8865109#8865109) thread.

Comment: It does work with a placeholder attribute. I actually found a workaround  with a small jquery plugin.

Comment: You can post it as a solution here.

Answer (score 0):

I am working around this issue with this jquery plugin:
https://github.com/mathiasbynens/jquery-placeholder